# Как задать слайдеру числовые значения через Qline в Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

В моей программе необходимо ввести числовое значение в поле QLine так, чтобы оно влияло на положение слайдера. Поля с цветной обводкой - QLine, над ними, соответственно, слайдеры.
Значения со слайдера влияют на значения в полях QLine.

[image: Интерфейс]

Comment: Разобрался сам. Мне было необходимо ввести условие: если значение в Qline не равно нулю, то через setvalue передаём его значение (в int) слайдеру:


if (R!=0)
   {
       SR->QSlider::setValue(rn);
   }
R - значение в Qline, SR - слайдер, rn - значение R в int

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось реализовать вашу задачу, но я использовал QSlider.

[image: Программа]

```
//mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(ui->HSli->value()));
    ui->label_2->setText(QString::number(ui->HSli_2->value()));
    ui->label_3->setText(QString::number(ui->HSli_3->value()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_HSli_valueChanged(int value)
{
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(ui->HSli->value()));
}

void MainWindow::on_HSli_2_valueChanged(int value)
{
    ui->label_2->setText(QString::number(ui->HSli_2->value()));
}

void MainWindow::on_HSli_3_valueChanged(int value)
{
    ui->label_3->setText(QString::number(ui->HSli_3->value()));
}



//mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int value);

    void on_HSli_valueChanged(int value);

    void on_HSli_2_valueChanged(int value);

    void on_HSli_3_valueChanged(int value);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    int w,h;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```